# PHP Московкое время выводится на час больше, чем есть сейчас

Tags: php, timezone

Следующий код PHP показывает время Москвы на час больше, чем на самом деле:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('H:i:s'), '<br>';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date('H:i:s');
```

Выводит:

```
13:24:57
17:24:57
```

Системное время на сервере в UTC.

Но при этом время Екатеринбурга (GMT+6) показывается верно.

В чем может быть дело?
Спасибо!

Comment: дело в том, что тандем экспериментирует с временем, и php не успевают править. я поставил `date.timezone = "Etc/GMT-3"` - работает. А в 5.6 уже все нормально

Comment: @splash58 любители по экспериментировать :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам достаточно обновить базу временных зон – PECL пакет [timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).

[Прямая ссылка](http://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb) на скачивание свежей версии.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить версию php > 5.5.18
Судя по тестам в ней этот баг пофикшен:

https://3v4l.org/Ed67N